# Why do I get these warnings even though the headers are included?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

GCC is spitting warnings, which make no sense for me. I've the needed **`stdio`** library included. The execution of this program works as expected and I got 100% points on EDX too. Also what are these warnings about **`size 6`** and **`size 5`**?

**Code so far:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
      char name[50];
      int age;
      struct student *next;
};

struct student *createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge);
struct student * append(struct student * end, struct student * newStudptr);
void printStudents(struct student *start);
void copyStr(char [], char []);
/* add other prototypes here if needed*/

int main(void) {
    struct student *start, *newStudptr, *end, *tmp;
    int ageP, ageR, ageM;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &ageP, &ageR, &ageM);

    start = createStudent("Petra", ageP);
    end = start;

    newStudptr = createStudent("Remi", ageR);
    end = append(end, newStudptr);

    newStudptr = createStudent("Mike", ageM);
    end = append(end, newStudptr);

    printStudents(start);
    tmp = start->next;

    free(start);

    start = tmp;
    tmp = start->next;

    free(start);
    free(tmp);

    return 0;
}

struct student* createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge) {
    struct student* newStud;

    newStud = (struct student*) malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    copyStr(studentName, newStud->name);
    newStud->age = studentAge;
    newStud->next = NULL;

    return newStud;
}

struct student* append(struct student* end, struct student* newStudPtr) {
    end->next = newStudPtr;
    end = newStudPtr;

    return end;
}

void copyStr(char source[], char target[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while(source[i] != '\0') {
        target[i] = source[i];
        i++;
    }

    target[i] = '\0';
}

void printStudents(struct student* start) {
    struct student* ptr = start;

    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s is %d years old.\n", ptr->name, ptr->age);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

/* Place your function definitions here. Be sure to include the definitions for 
   createStudent() and append() as well as any other functions you created for 
   the previous tasks. */
```

**The warnings:**

```
:!gcc -Wall -std=c17 edx_PrintLinkedList.c -o bin/edx_PrintLinkedList                                                                                                                 
edx_PrintLinkedList.c: In function ‘main’:
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:22:13: warning: ‘createStudent’ accessing 50 bytes in a region of size 6 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   22 |     start = createStudent("Petra", ageP);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:22:13: note: referencing argument 1 of type ‘char *’
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:45:17: note: in a call to function ‘createStudent’
   45 | struct student* createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:25:18: warning: ‘createStudent’ accessing 50 bytes in a region of size 5 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   25 |     newStudptr = createStudent("Remi", ageR);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:25:18: note: referencing argument 1 of type ‘char *’
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:45:17: note: in a call to function ‘createStudent’
   45 | struct student* createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:28:18: warning: ‘createStudent’ accessing 50 bytes in a region of size 5 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   28 |     newStudptr = createStudent("Mike", ageM);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:28:18: note: referencing argument 1 of type ‘char *’
edx_PrintLinkedList.c:45:17: note: in a call to function ‘createStudent’
   45 | struct student* createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge) {
```

Comment: You told the compiler you are expecting an array of 50 characters, but give it only 5 or 6 characters. Change char name[50] to char* name. Think about what you do if strlen(name) >= 50.

Comment: alright ;D sadly im not allowed to change any lines that were given by edx! only add my own but now i know the "bug" ty ACTUALLY i can edit the functin where i pass the array size.

Comment: You don't have to state the size, as in function `void copyStr(char source[], char target[])`. C ignores that size anyway: in a function's array argument it is only needed for the inner dimensions of a multi-dimensional array (so the compiler can figure out the indexing).

Answer (score 1):

we dont know which lines you can change or not

But gcc is complainng about this

you say

```
   struct student* createStudent(char studentName[50], int studentAge)
```

but then you do

```
   start = createStudent("Petra", ageP);
```

which is trying to invoke it as a

```
  struct student* createStudent(char studentName[6], int studentAge)
```

function

can you do

```
  struct student* createStudent(char studentName[], int studentAge)
```

That will work

edit

---

YOu can also fix it like this

```
  char name[50];
  ....
  strcpy(name, "Petra");
  start = createStudent(name, ageP);
```

Comment: I already now the reason for these warnings, sadly its restricted for me to change given code lines. I can only add my lines of code :D still ty for this good explanation really silly by me to not recognize this by myselfe